# Add a fetched drop down box using Ajax query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am beginner on `Php` and `Ajax`. I am developing a system which contain of `table` and each column of the `table` consists `HTML inputs`. Whenever I clicked the `button` new row would be appear and contains `inputs` using `ajax query` (followed by a tutorial - `Multiple Inline Insert into Mysql using Ajax JQuery in PHP`).

All column contains text field and except one `field`, which is a `drop down box` fetched from `database` and contains of `database` values. Here I tried to do something all the inputs will be appear but I couldn't understand how to `query` the `fetched drop down box` to appear whenever I clicked the button:

The code as follows:

```
<!-- TABLE START -->
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
    <!-- <div class="card-box"> -->
     <div class="card-block">
     <!-- <h4 class="card-title">Hover Rows</h4> -->
   <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-bordered mb-0" id="tab">
        <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th >Medicine Name</th>
                  <th>Morning</th>
                  <th>Noon</th>
                  <th>Night</th>
                  <th>Charge</th>
                  <th> </th>

              </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    <td class="medicine">    


                      <div class="col-md-12">
                       <select class="select" id="med">
                       <option>Select</option>

                        <?php  
    include 'auth/dbconnection.php';
    $query = "SELECT * FROM medicines ";
    if($result = mysqli_query($conn,$query));
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    foreach($result as $row){
        echo '<option value="2">'.$row['med_id'].'</option>';

    }
    }}
    ?>
        </select>
              </div> 

               </td>

                <td contenteditable="true" class="morning">dfdfdfd</td>
                <td contenteditable="true" class="noon">Doe</td>
                <td contenteditable="true" class="night">Doe</td>
                <td class="charge">Doe</td>
                <td class=""></td>

                 <br>  <br>
                 </tr>

                    </tbody>
                    </table>
                       <br>
              <div align="right"> 
          <!-- <input type="submit" name="add" id="add"  class="btn btn-success" value="">   -->

          <button type="button" id="add" name="add"  class="btn btn-success">+</button>
                    </div>
                      </div>
                     <!-- </div> -->
                     </div>
                        </div>
                         </div>
                           </div>
                           </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>

      <?php     }

    }
    else{

    }  ?>
```

Here is my Ajax query code:

```
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){

    var count=1;
    $('#add').click(function() {
        count= count+1;  
        var html_code= "<tr id='row"+count+"'>";
        html_code += "<td class='medicine'> <select class='select' id='med'>
        <option value="2">'.$row['med_id'].'</option>'

  </select></td>";

        html_code += "<td contenteditable='true' class='morning'> </td>";
        html_code += "<td contenteditable='true' class='noon'> </td>";
        html_code += "<td contenteditable='true' class='night'> </td>";
        html_code += "<td contenteditable='true' class='charge'> </td>";
        html_code += "<td> <button type='button' name='remove' id='remove' data-row='row"+count+"' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs remove' >  -  </button> </td>";
        html_code +=  "</tr>";

        $('#tab').append(html_code);

    });




    $('#med').editableSelect();
            });
    </script>
```

[Screen shot of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwF1E.png)

Please help me to solve this problem. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: @DCTID: what would be expected. link went wrong

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm not exactly sure what you need help with. Please read [how to write a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question

Comment: Be aware an id must be unique in a document.

Comment: @Gerard in my `ajax query` .I coded to insert a new row with elements except `drop down` box which was fetched from database. I cannot understand how to `query`. Please help me

Comment: Please make an effort to separate the database and service-related code from presentation (html) code. This is why PHP gets a bad name.

Comment: @cnizzardini in this case what would I do?

Comment: You'd use classes, set the output of calls to the medicines to an array, then pass the array of medicines to your view (html) and loop over that to build your dropdown.

Comment: As for your specific question. You are not making an AJAX call, yet you are trying to use AJAX to build a list? $('#add').click should make an AJAX call https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ and you will need to have an endpoint to return that data as JSON, then loop over the JSON and build your list.

Comment: @cnizzardini  yes I  have tried to build a list of `tables`, but the question is how to build a `fetched drop down box..?` Just I can create a `normal drop down box`, but the situation is to built a `fetched drop down box...`

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Comment: @cnizzardini want to create a `fetched drop down box`...